# win the assembly elections (with a) sweeping majority

Tags: sentence-construction

> The candidate was likely to win the assembly elections (with a) sweeping majority.

My exam says "with a" should be replaced as "by a", but this doesn't sound correct to me.

can you help me out?

---

Answer (score 2):

The idioms are all "To win by something"

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/win+by+a+nose

[image]